# Lua 5.2 Can't access function in C library

Tags: c, api, lua

I have written this simple library:

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

static int l_or(lua_State *l)
{
  int i, result = 0;
  int nargs = lua_gettop(l);
  for(i = 1; i <= nargs; ++i)
  {
    result |= lua_tointeger(l, i);
  }

  lua_pushnumber(l, result);
  return 1;
}

static const luaL_Reg mybit [] = {
  {"or", l_or},
  {NULL, NULL}  /* sentinel */
};

int __declspec(dllexport) luaopen_mybit (lua_State *L)
{
      luaL_newlibtable(L, mybit);
      luaL_setfuncs(L, mybit,0);
      return 1;
}
```

Compiled to a DLL called mylib.dll.

Which I then test using the standalone Lua interpreter using the following script:

```
print ("Test script")

mybit = require("mybit")
print(mybit)

mybit.or(1,2,3)
--print(mybit.or)
```

When I run the script I get the following output:

```
lua: test.lua:6: <name> expected near 'or'
```

According to all the examples I have looked at this should be perfectly ok. If I comment out mybit.or(1,2,3) I get

```
Test script
table: 005A8EB8
```

So I am fairly confident that the library is being loaded. My problem is that I can't understand why I can't access the or function using the dot operator.

I am using Lua 5.2 compiled with mingw-gcc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`or` is a reserved word in Lua (it's the logical or operator). This is why all existing bitwise operation libraries in Lua name the or-function something like `bor`. `and` and `not` are similarly reserved. (The complete list of reserved words can be found [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.1).)

You can still call it by using a string:

```
print(mybit["or"](1,2,3))
print(mybit["or"])
```

But you're better off following the example of existing bitwise operation libraries and naming it something other than `or`.

Comment: I had managed to call the function using a string when I was trying to get it to work. It didn't seem very elegant though - I didn't realise until it was pointed out that I had used one of the reserved words.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `or` as the function name which is a keyword in Lua, try another name, like `my_or`.

Comment: That's worked, thanks. I guess this is a case where nearly any other example would have worked first time!

Comment: @jgashby Some languages have both `||` and `or` as keyword. For Lua, there's only `or`. BTW, I think a more easily forgotten keyword in Lua is `in`.